# Use of request in @Route's condition option

Tags: php, routes, annotations, symfony

I have a controller that renders a fragment of a page; and it may be refreshed using ajax. Until now, this controller uses this at the top:

```
    if ('/_fragment' !== $request->getPathInfo() && !$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
```

This works well, but I seen that [there is a `condition` option in the `@Route` annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions), and wanted to use it instead:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/widget/render/{cryptedId}",
 *     name = "widget_render",
 *     requirements = {
 *         "cryptedId" = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
 *     },
 *     condition = "'/_fragment' == request.getPathInfo() or  request.isXmlHttpRequest()"
 * )
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template()
 */
```

But adding this option gives me the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in appDevUrlMatcher.php line 319:
-> Error: Call to a member function getPathInfo() on a non-object
```

That's strange, because from the documentation, `context` and `request` are available in the expression parser. By looking at the source code, in [UrlMatcher.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L210), we can see that they should be available:

```
    if ($route->getCondition() && !$this->getExpressionLanguage()->evaluate($route->getCondition(), array('context' => $this->context, 'request' => $this->request))) {
        return array(self::REQUIREMENT_MISMATCH, null);
    }
```

I really don't get the point. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your condition in my Symfony3.0 app and it works perfectly, so I think the problem is somwhere else than in your condition definition.

Comment: You are right, it works on an empty project. I must have a vendor bundle that conflicts, will investigate this way. Thanks